# Реверс слов в предложении

Tags: java

Всем привет! В IDEA работает, а проверка выдает:

> Failed test #1 of 6. Runtime error
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
>       at Main.reverse(Main.java:8)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:15)

Задача. Реализуйте метод для обращения заданного массива строк. Массив может иметь любой размер. Метод может обратить и вернуть существующий массив или вернуть новый массив.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static String[] reverse(String... words) {
        // write your code here
    }

    /* Do not change code below */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        String[] reversed = reverse(words);
        Arrays.stream(reversed).forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
    }
}
```

Мой код.

```
public static String[] reverse(String[] words) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(words);
        Collections.reverse(list);
        return (String[]) list.toArray();
```

Comment: `return list.toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: @Serodv, как-то слишком сомнительно выглядит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу:

```
public static String[] reverse(String[] words) {
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(words));
    return words;
}
```

Всего лишь нужно было убрать list.toArray()

Ну а если вам интересно почему это работает, то я вам скажу. Дело в том что Arrays.asList() создает представление над массивом, таким образом вызов метода set() на этом списке будет изменять исходный массив.